# How to add a shadow to SlidingTabLayout at the bottom

Tags: android

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_bg" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So far I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#70d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#60d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#50d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#40d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#30d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#20d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#10d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

            <solid android:color="#00d8d8d8" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/actionbar_bg" />

            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

However it is not giving me the desired result, I want something like:

[image]

Comment: add elevation to tablayout android:elevation="2dp"

Comment: That will only work with API level 21

Comment: what was the solution you went with in the end? thx

Comment: Dont remember, sorry! I think this is provided out of the box now with toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Add simple `View` between `com.example.SlidingTabLayout` and `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. Set background for that `View` as gradient which mimics shadow.

**shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#20000000"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:angle="90">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

**Edit:** if you need a shadow which should be drawn on top of `ViewPager`, then move `ViewPager` and `View` with shadow background in `RelativeLayout`. 
It's good when you don't have sources of `SlidingTabLayout`. In case, when you have source code, you can add shadow drawing from the code, overriding `onDraw` method in `SlidingTabLayout`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that its not transparent, your views clip when scrolling. I want an effect wherein the shadow is applied without the clipping part.

Comment: if you need transparent shadow, just add alpha to gradient colors. android:startColor="#55404040", android:endColor="#55F1F1F1"

Comment: Brother the views will still clip, the shadow needs to be transparent and floating, so that anything scrolling below the view is visible, one solution to that would be to use a frame layout.

Comment: if you place your ViewPager before shadow View in RelativeLayout, then shadow will be drawn on top of ViewPager content.

Comment: I am looking at the alternate idea you provided - onDraw!